# Page Set up for multiple worksheets and Print

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with over a hundred sheets.  I have been able to fix the column width and rows heights so that it is a good printable format for each.  I'm having difficulty putting in order a code to do the following:

1. Set the print area for each sheet [This is variable since each sheet may contain different amount of rows] - Each sheet has the same headers on the first row and the header runs from A1:N1.  All the data starts at row 2 and how ever many rows down depending on each sheet.
2. I would like the header row to be the title on each page if multiple pages need to be printed
3. Set the format to landscape
4. I want the scaling to fit all the columns in one page.  If it has to print to multiple pages that will be if there are may rows.
5. Print all the worksheets

I know the code below has xlPortrait as the orientation where it should be landscape.  My problem is I can't get the initial part going.  I've been trying to do it in pieces but I can't seem to get it started.  Any help in the right direction will be great.

```
 Sub SetupPrint()
Dim wkst As Worksheet
    For Each wkst In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        With wkst.PageSetup.PrintArea
        .Range(("A1"), Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select

        End With


        With wkst.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .FitToPagesWide = 1

        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I wanted to automate the process. I realize that I could set the landscape, fit all the columns to one page, and print all the sheets by selecting all the worksheet tabs.  I couldn't get to apply the first row of setting the titles for each page.  I ended up recording what I did and ran the macro to apply it to each page.  Then I printed all the worksheets by selecting all the tabs.

Comment: I found my solution but I'm always trying to learn what VBA can do to eliminate as much manual effort in the future.  Sometimes the cost-benefit is not there but it may be useful at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You've got basically everything there.

If each worksheet has the same Number of columns and save headings, then you don't need to set the print area for each sheet. Just specify to fit all columns in on one page and that will make it print all columns on 1 page and it'll print however many pages it needs to print all the rows.

so you've got your `.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"` that'll do the headings

you've got the portrait but as stated that needs to be landscape

The fitToPagesWide = 1 I believe will fit all columns on each page

You could add `.FitToPagesTall = False` for safety sake

And then the code to print is `ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False`

I don't know what collate is.. experiment with that.

Basically the way I got this code was I went to view - macro's - record macro
Then I set the page layout in the workbook to what I wanted, and then I stopped the macro and checked the code and it had the code to set all the settings how I did.

Another alternative - There's no real reason to use VBA for this. go to the "Print titles" on the page layout tab to get the column headings to print on each page, then hit CTRL+P to go to print, you can set all the other print settings there including all columns on one page, then make sure it's set to "Print Entire Workbook".. that'll accomplish the same